PL/1 PUT SKIP(n) not skipping lines
For line no 7 & 9, SYSPRINT display does not SKIP to 3rd line. Instead I'm getting in SYSPRINT as below:
1HELLO 1 !
-HELLO 1 !
3                       4                       5
-X=        3             Y=        4             Z=        5;
Why SKIP(n) is not working as expected (should SKIP to nth line from current line)? What is the 1, - signs at the beginning of the lines in SYSPRINT?
000001  PROG: PROC OPTIONS(MAIN);               
000002         DCL (X,Y,Z)  FIXED BIN(15,0);    
000003         X=3;                             
000004         Y=4;                             
000005         Z=5;                             
000006         PUT LIST('HELLO 1 !');           
000007         PUT SKIP(3) LIST('HELLO 1 !');   
000008         PUT LIST(X,Y,Z) SKIP;            
000009         PUT DATA(X,Y,Z) SKIP(3);         
000010  END PROG;                               


The characters in column 1 are ASA printer control characters.
A minus in column one means advance the page by three lines and continue printing from there, so exactly what your SKIP(3) intends to do.
SKIP(4) would print a minus in column 1, followed by an empty line and your output on the next etc.
PL/I will use those control characters on all files with record-format FBA or VBA - it's actually the meaning of the A.
If you don't want those control characters you will have to write your output to some FB or VB file you define in your JCL.
